# What am I doing wrong to receive Loopback and REST API WordPress Errors?

Tags: windows, nginx, networking, wordpress

I've taken a dive into self hosting and learning along the way. I have a decent understanding of most of it. It only took me a day to cobble together a "working" NGINX, MySQL, PHP, phpMyAdmin and SSL. I am doing this purely for the educational purposes and fun. A playground if you will.

Version information is here:

[image: Version information is here].

SSL acquired by LetsEncrypt via certbot. The host is Windows Server 2016 Standard 10.0.14393 x64.

I've currently ran into a few problems.

- WordPress Error: `The REST API request failed due to an error: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10010 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (http_request_failed)`
- WordPress Error: `The loopback request to your site failed, this means features relying on them are not currently working as expected: cURL error 28: Operation timed out after 10008 milliseconds with 0 bytes received (http_request_failed)`

I have looked through some logs and can't make heads or tails of it. I have spent a solid day trying random things I have come across. Because WordPress has zero plugins enabled or installed, and only one theme installed and used (default 2020), I am led to believe this is an issue with the server configuration. For reference, here are both the files used by NGINX:

- [nginx.conf](https://gist.github.com/icedterminal/a43fd6c076e15d261ef365631a5af1c8)
- [wordpress.conf](https://gist.github.com/icedterminal/2760b1b2dabff4c5d9437b451cc8cb7a)

WordPress *appears* to function fine. But I prefer no errors. I'm not sure where the breakdown is for this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: seems like you're using FastCGI and PHP-FPM, you may remove `proxy_*` configurations. Try adapting [nginx' official Wordpress sample](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/recipes/wordpress/) configuration for your server.

Comment: @mforsetti I did find that help page and ported over some of that content since I posted. However, your suggestion of removing the `proxy` variable got me somewhere. Instead of empty timeouts, it's now a 403.

Comment: 403 should come from bad permissions, please update your `wordpress.conf` gist.

Comment: Why on earth is this on Windows? And how is this Windows server connected to the Internet?

Comment: @mforsetti I will update the gist. Sadly, after a reboot of the system it went back to timeout.

Comment: @MichaelHampton Linux distros I have used on this computer will inexplicably pop up a crash about an internal error after about a day of uptime. I have literally left if alone after fresh installing. I debugged it and it stems from an ACPI error with the motherboard firmware. After that stuff starts acting up. It is out of my control. I'm just having fun here so don't judge me. [This is on consumer-grade "gaming" hardware.](https://github.com/icedterminal/ga-z270x-ug/wiki) Connected via ethernet if that's what you're asking.

Comment: *Where* are you running this? This is quite an important information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have solved it. It is two part.

Running `curl -v example.com` returned a failure with my initial conf. After making some changes, I managed to get a 200. Those changes are to the wordpress.conf file:

```
upstream php {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
}

server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl http2;
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    server_name www.domain.com;

    # truncated conf
}
```

The crucial part here is `www` for `server_name` which I did not have before. My DNS records don't require `www`. If I remove `www` the request fails. This also explains why when I typed `www.example.com` in the URL box I got a 403. I had an improper server setup there. Now it properly redirects any URL combination of `http/https` or the presence/absence of `www` to `https://example.com`. After posting the question I also ended up finding the missing `upstream php` block and added that. See comments on the question.

Loopbacks worked, but to a degree. WordPress was still saying there was an error. [Thanks to these two comments, I found out why](https://www.php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.php#121890). To complete the loopback you need PHP FPM. Which does not exist for Windows. You can get around this by having nginx spawn an additional `php-cgi.exe` process through the use of `upstream php` like so:

```
upstream php {
    server 127.0.0.1:9000;
    server 127.0.0.1:9001;
}
```

This allows nginx to process the loopback requested by WordPress and then the error goes away, as I observed. Unfortunately, this is not viable. Just like the comment said, the `php-cgi.exe` processes will eventually crash. Resulting in PHP completely stopping breaking the site.

Looks like I need Linux after all. Might have to change hardware that doesn't cause Linux to bug out.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your system is not able to make callbacks to itself. This looks like a network or environment issue (f.e. using a DNS name that loops back to the same system but is wrongly routed and/or blocked by a firewall).

Anyway, it's not possible to answer this question without a lot more details.

And, last but not least, home/lab environments are explicitly off-topic here.